# Facebook Connect - Mobile

Tags: php, mobile, facebook

I am currently in the process of creating a mobile version of my web app.
The app is being developed with Facebook's PHP Client Library.

The issue:

I am using the following mobile url to allow users to log in using the mobile devices:
http://m.facebook.com/tos.php?api_key=APIKEY&v=1.0&next=http%3A%2F%2Ftweelay.net%2Fm.php&cancel=http%3A%2F%2Ftweelay.net%2Fm.php

APIKEY being my app's actual Facebook API key.

In the url I am telling Facebook to redirect the user back to `http://tweelay.net/m.php` when the user signs in or clicks cancel on the log in screen. I am pulling my hair trying to figure out why it keeps sending the user to `http://m.tweelay.net/m.php` which is currently an invalid end point.

I have gone through all of my app's settings on Facebook and I cant find any that reference `http://m.tweelay.net` and going through all of my source code I cant find any that reference the `m.` sub-domain either.

Any ideas? Is there a setting I'm missing? Maybe a Flag in the library?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure it isn't your webserver rewriting the URL based on the User Agent ID sent by the mobile browser? Does the same behavior occur if you use a desktop web browser?

Comment: it happens on both my mobile and my browser

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Facebook do this when detecting the mobile browser type and also sometimes randomly through Firefox (it can also happen when trying to get to facebook.com).  I've managed to reset it sometimes, but it's not a guaranteed fix.

If you want to be sure the user makes it to your correct site I suggest creating the subdomain and redirecting traffic to your usual site, it's what I did and now I don't worry about it reverting back.

Comment: Thats what I am currently doing but it feels like kind of a hack. Really hoping to avoid going this route. But +1 for a working work-around. :)